# ?AspectRatio? setting to obtain equal length pr pixel on all axes

Tags: plotting

Like these does:

```
Show[Graphics[Rectangle[{2, 1}, {15, 2}]]]
ParametricPlot[{t,t t},{t,0,2}]
```

how do I create a `Plot[]` with axes having equal variable length pr. pixel?
My first idea was

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{}, {t, 0, 1}], Plot[t, {t, 0, 1}]]
```

But that messes with the `PlotRange` and possibly more...

Comment: I think this is what you want (please confirm): `Plot[t, {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: Ye, right, guess I forgot Automatic is not standard

Comment: It is for `ParametricPlot`, but for `Plot` it is `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio`.  You can always change this with `SetOptions`.  Incidentally you will find a lot of questions that may be of interest with [this search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=AspectRatio+Automatic).